# Finding the inverse of my f(x) function that includes a fractional exponent (with a variable in the fraction)

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, inverse-function

Im a noob mathematician.

I am trying to find the inverse of this function:
$$F(x) = \frac{x + 299 \cdot 2^\frac{x-1}{7}}{4} $$

In the same way that: $$f(y) = ½(y - 1)$$ is the inverse of: $$f(x) = 2x + 1$$

I know the procedure goes along like this:

1) Let y = f(x)

2) Swap the x"s and y"s

3) Solve with y as the subject

The problem im having is with the exponent: (x-1)/7. I'm not sure what to do with it so that I can solve for y.

If someone could solve this for me that would be great. I am also interested in the steps to the solution, so including the steps would be a bonus.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Lambert $W$ function, also known as the productlog function, might be worth looking at. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: I say this because I did have Wolfram Alpha calculate the inverse (https://goo.gl/Qy4ehs) and it uses the $W$ function. So finding this inverse is not going to be trivial. I'm trying to figure out how to do so myself but the $W$ function isn't my area of expertise. (Deleted and reposted this comment because I found the inverse of the wrong thing and then had trouble linking to it. Still uses the $W$ function though.)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thanks for linking to wolfram and mentioning the W function. I saw this get mentioned in other inverse-function questions, but since they did not exactly match my exponent I was hoping it wouldn't apply to me. *sigh* I guess I have to learn something new now.

Comment: Well learning something new is _always_ a good thing.

Comment: The substitution  $u=x+4F(x)$ greatly simplifies the equation.

Answer (score 1):

In general the equation,

$$e^{-cx}=a_0\left(x-r \right)$$

Has [solution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function),

$$r+\frac{1}{c} W(\frac{ce^{-cr}}{a_0})=x$$

The reason is below this line.

---

Using the lambert W function. Let $x-r=u$ so that $x=r+u$.

$$e^{-c(r+u)}=a_0 u $$

$$e^{-cr}e^{-cu}=a_0u$$

$$e^{-cu}=a_0e^{cr} u$$

$$1=a_0e^{cr} u e^{cu}$$

$$\frac{e^{-cr}}{a_0}=u e^{cu}$$

$$\frac{ce^{-cr}}{a_0}=cu e^{cu}$$

$$W(\frac{ce^{-cr}}{a_0})=cu$$

$$\frac{1}{c} W(\frac{ce^{-cr}}{a_0})=u$$

$$r+\frac{1}{c} W(\frac{ce^{-cr}}{a_0})=x$$

---

The equation you have written can be rearranged to the form considered previously.

$$4F=x+299(2^{-\frac{1}{7}}) e^{x \frac{\ln 2}{7}}$$

$$\frac{4F-x}{299}=2^{-\frac{1}{7}} e^{x \frac{\ln 2}{7}}$$

$$\frac{2^{\frac{1}{7}}}{299} \left( 4F-x \right)=e^{ x \frac{\ln 2}{7}}$$

$$\frac{-2^{\frac{1}{7}}}{299} \left( x-4F \right)=e^{ x \frac{\ln 2}{7}}$$

Thus, to find the inverse use  $r=4x$, $a_0= \frac{-2^{\frac{1}{7}}}{299}$, and $c=-\frac{\ln 2}{7}$.